# MySQL connection is gone Java

Tags: java, mysql

I have a Java web app that interacts with MySQL DB. I never close a DB connection and i use singleton to work with the connection instance.

The problem is, after I keep the connection open for too long and I try to do some action on the app, I am getting this error:

```
The last packet successfully received from the server was 211,710,369 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 211,710,398 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
```

Any idea how can I make `autoReconnect=true`? Or why is this happening? I though it would automatically reconnect by default. Or should I keep closing the DB after every request? That is decreasing performance which is crucial with this app.

Any more information I can provide?

Comment: Are you truly letting a connection sit idle for 2.45 days?

Comment: If the connection sits idle for 2½ days then opening and closing connections is not going to be a performance issue.

Comment: Classic. Performance concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you should not let the connection open for that long .. but to answer to your question about autoReconnect. its a property one can set in the connection url like for e.g

```
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/confluence?autoReconnect=true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following to keep connection alive

First use this for mysql connection

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/<database>?autoReconnect=true
```

Use validation query to keep connection live for inactive connections also for long time.

http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/tomcat-jdbc-connection-pool-configuration-for-production-and-development/

In springboot application you can do it by adding following in your configuration

```
datasource.primary.testWhileIdle=true    
datasource.primary.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=10000    
datasource.primary.validationQuery=SELECT 1    
datasource.primary.testOnBorrow=true
```